# The endpoint api gateway test passes normally, but when deployed, I get error 404

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Help me please. What have I done wrong. I want to have access to ec2 via api gataway and wrote a cloudformation template

```
     paths:
      /{proxy+}:
        x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
          headers:
             Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
               type: "string"
             Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                type: "string"
             Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                type: "string"
             Content-Type:
                 type: "string"
             authority:
                 type: "string"
          produces:
          - "application/json"
          parameters:
          - name: "proxy"
            in: "path"
            required: false
            type: "string"
          responses: {}
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            responses:
              default:
                statusCode: "200"
            uri: "http://ec2-1111111111.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/{proxy}"
            requestParameters:
              integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'text/html'"
              "integration.request.path.proxy": "method.request.path.proxy"
            passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
            httpMethod: ANY
            type: "http_proxy
```

for this where I defined 1 endpoint http_proxy. When I test this endpoint everything works fine, but as soon as I deploy api and try to get access through the browser, error 404 crashes

Comment: Have you checked your API gateway logs in CloudWatch?

Comment: After removing and redeploying the stack, I achieved the page display, but external css works incorrect

Answer (score 0):

After removing and redeploying the stack, I achieved the page display, but still I can’t ensure that the connected css files are connected correctly.

[image]